# Device Token returns from the APNS but the devices not registering in ET

Tags: marketing-cloud, community, ios, mobilepush

Already my app was having 6.0 deployment target and I was able to see all the devices are registering in ET without any problems.

But After updating the deployment target to 9.0 I can see the device is not registering in ET. But still I can see the device token is available in `didRegisterForRemoteNotifications`.

I can see all my OLD devices still getting push notifications. But ET last registration date has not changed.

New devices will not registering in ET

Please advice me, if any work around this.

Answer (score 0):

Push notification registration changed in iOS 8. You're probably looking for [`-[UIApplication registerUserNotificationSettings:]`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIApplication/registerUserNotificationSettings:). The previous API, `-[UIApplication registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:]`, is now deprecated.

Comment: hi Jonathon, Thank you

But I can see the the devices are registering on APNS and the device token has received.